# What is a neural network called which generates new outputs

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to make a neural network which will generate new surnames. Although, while thinking about this I realized that this problem can not be solved with a traditional neural network because I want it to find a pattern in my dataset and generate a new surname. Which type of AI should I use? Where can I learn it from?

PS
My project is inspired by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pG6uj0etY5Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe GANs?

https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-are-generative-adversarial-networks-gans/

Although I did find this which uses RNN and seems far more straightforward:

[https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-pokémon-names-using-rnns-f41003143333](https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-pok%C3%A9mon-names-using-rnns-f41003143333)

Answer (score 1):

Neural Networks, use with the aim to generate something, called **Generative Adversarial Network (GAN)**.

While in your case, you might have to go with variations of RNN (LSTM/ GRU) because names are based on language and sequence of alphabets.